# Cannot load from object array because "this.list" is null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, serial-port, ide, processing

When I am running Processing sometimes the code works and many times I am getting this error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.list" is null"

I know it's regarding Null Pointer Exception but as a newbie I can't figure out how to rewrite to solve this problem.

Code:

```
import processing.serial.*;

Serial port;
String[] list;
String myString = null;
int ai, bi;
  
void setup(){
  
  fullScreen();
  //size(800, 500);
  
  port = new Serial(this, "COM6", 9600);
  port.clear();
  
  myString = port.readStringUntil('\n');
  myString = null;
  
}

void draw(){
  
  background(0);
  textSize(30);
  
  while (port.available() > 0) {
    myString = port.readStringUntil('\n');
  } 
    list = split(myString, ',');
    
    float a, b;
    PFont f = createFont("Arial", 64);
    textFont(f);
    textSize(90);
    
    a = float(list[0]);
    b = float(list[1]);
    ai = round (a);
    bi = round (b);
    println("Displacement: " + ai + " mm " + "Pressure: " + bi + " kg");
    text("Displacement: " + ai + " mm ", 10, 100);
    text("Pressure: " + bi + " kg ", 10, 200);
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `split` method?

Comment: Brother this is the entire code. I don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: At what line do you get the Null Pointer Exception ?

Comment: Brother issue is solved.....

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is because you access `list[0]`, `list[1]` when it's empty.

Try changing

```
a = float(list[0]);
b = float(list[1]);
```

to:

```
if (list != null){
  a = float(list[0]);
  b = float(list[1]); 
}
```

and hopefully it works.

Comment: I tried this code now. Now I am getting a new error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "this.list" is null

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please try that too.

Comment: Thanks a lot cSharp. Instead of (list !== null), it will be (list != null). You are awesome. If I still face any problem in future I will let you know. Thanks again you made my day :) 

Comment: Right, I've edited my answer. Too much javascript lately.

Comment: Thanks a lot again cSharp. I am actually taking readings from arduino using serial port. I am taking 2 separate data, and then processing it for display. I was facing this problem for 3 straight days. I was shocked to see that sometimes it compiles and sometimes it crashes. Thanks a lot. YOU ARE AWESOMEEEEEEEE......